# Converting C# Linq to Vb.Net Linq

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I am getting a DataTable from sql server using a stored proc. The following shows a simplified verion of the data

```cs
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Products");
dt.Columns.Add("ProductID");
dt.Columns.Add("CustomerID");
dt.Columns.Add("CustomerState");
dt.Columns.Add("CustomerCity");

//DataRow row1 = table1.NewRow();
object[] o = { 1, 1, "TX", "Austin" };
dt.Rows.Add(o);

object[] o1 = { 2, 2, "AZ", "Phoenix" };
dt.Rows.Add(o1);

object[] o2 = { 2, 3, "OK", "Oklahoma" };
dt.Rows.Add(o2);

object[] o3 = { 2, 4, "CO", "Denver" };
dt.Rows.Add(o3);

object[] o4 = { 3, 1, "TX", "Austin" };
dt.Rows.Add(o4);
```

I am planning to group the data by ProductID. After grouping there should be only one row for each ProductID. If there are multiple ProductIDs then the others fields should be concatenated delimited by a semicolon as shown below.

| ProductID | CustomerID | CustomerState | CustomerCity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | TX | Austin |
| 2 | 2;3;4 | AZ;OK;CO | Phoenix;Oklahoma;Denver |
| 3 | 1 | TX | Austin |

The following code written in C# works fine.

```cs
var results = from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
    group p by p.Field<string>("Productid") into g
    select new
    {
        ProductId = g.Key,
        CustomerId = string.Join(";", from i in g select i.Field<string>("CustomerID")),
        CustomerState = string.Join(";", from i in g select i.Field<string>("CustomerState")),
        CustomerCity = string.Join(";", from i in g select i.Field<string>("CustomerCity")),
    };
```

However I have to work on an VB.Net project, and I am very new to VB.Net. I tried several code convertors, which convert C# to VB.Net but none of them work.

The closest I could come up with was as shown below:

```vb
Dim results = From p In dt.AsEnumerable() 
    Group p By ProductID = p.Field(Of String)("ProductID") Into g = Group
    Select New With {
        Key .ProductID = g.Key,
        .CustomerId = String.Join(";", From i In g Select i.Field(Of String)("CustomerId")),
        .CustomerState= String.Join(";", From i In g Select i.Field(Of String)("CustomerState")),
        .CustomerCity= String.Join(";", From i In g Select i.Field(Of String)("CustomerCity"))
    }
```

But I am getting

> Key is not a member of 'IEnumerable(Of DataRow)'

on the line, `g.Key`

Comment: You do realize you can reference a c# project in vb.net and simply call methods of the referenced c# project ? eg. like described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44994962

Comment: What happens if you remove `Key` before `.ProductID= g.Key`? (I do not know VB Linq, but the examples I saw using `Select New With { ... }` didn't have a keyword or variable name `Key` in that position.)

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
Key .ProductID= g.Key
```

with:

```
Key .ProductId = ProductId
```

VB and C# LINQ were developed independently, so there are some quirky differences, such as not being able to use "g.Key" directly in VB. I can't really give you any logic about why this is so. I tested both your C# code and the VB code with the replacement above, and the same results are produced.

Also, regarding the "Key" keyword: in VB you should use it for all the fields of an anonymous type if you're converting from C#:

```
Key .CustomerId ...
Key .CustomerState ...
Key .CustomerCity ...
```

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks a lot. This worked. But when I tried to loop through the result I am getting System.InvalidCastException
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'VB$AnonymousType_1`4[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]' to type 'System.Data.DataRow' error. The code I used was: For Each result As String In results
                Dim x As String = result
            Next

Comment: @Massey: Does the loop work in C#? If so, can you edit your original post to include the loop?

Comment: @Massey: Also, for inferred typing to work in VB, you need to have Option Infer On. Otherwise you're dealing with 'Object'.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I am also a C# guy and converted using telerik converter)

What I did was to write the C# version in lambda form and remove those "Key" in resulting code. It works (tested in LinqPad):

```
Private Sub Main()
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable("Products")
    dt.Columns.Add("ProductID")
    dt.Columns.Add("CustomerID")
    dt.Columns.Add("CustomerState")
    dt.Columns.Add("CustomerCity")
    Dim o As Object() = {1, 1, "TX", "Austin"}
    dt.Rows.Add(o)
    Dim o1 As Object() = {2, 2, "AZ", "Phoenix"}
    dt.Rows.Add(o1)
    Dim o2 As Object() = {2, 3, "OK", "Oklahoma"}
    dt.Rows.Add(o2)
    Dim o3 As Object() = {2, 4, "CO", "Denver"}
    dt.Rows.Add(o3)
    Dim o4 As Object() = {3, 1, "TX", "Austin"}
    dt.Rows.Add(o4)
    Dim results = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(p) p.Field(Of String)("Productid")).Select(Function(g) New With {
        .ProductId = g.Key, 
        .CustomerId = String.Join(";", From i In g Select i.Field(Of String)("CustomerID")), 
        .CustomerState = String.Join(";", From i In g Select i.Field(Of String)("CustomerState")), 
        .CustomerCity = String.Join(";", From i In g Select i.Field(Of String)("CustomerCity"))
    })
    //results.Dump()
End Sub
```